# Return to same ID on multi-page after application pause

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create an phonegap/jquery mobile application but has stumple on an issue. Everything works just perfect. I have structured the page as an multi-page. When I pause my application to go to another application and wants to get back to my application it starts at the first page... How do I "lock" the application to the last page?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Retain in jStorage the last pageId and check in Resume event if there was any pageId in this jStorage value, if yes then change page to that page, which all this happens in back-end...you can meanwhile show loading icon with text "Resuming..."